# Sidebar modules duplicated

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar

As you can see, the sidebar features Meta, then the ad, then the chat ad, then Meta again, then the ad again, then the chat ad again (which fails to load), then finally related questions (once):

[image: The sidebar]

Props to GnomeSlice for noticing this first.

Comment: Also happened for me, though I could not consistency duplicate this.

Comment: in what browser? with extensions or add-ins? how do we repro this, never seen it..

Comment: @Jeff Safari, no, any question page.

Comment: @Jeff Try http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19066/is-call-of-duty-black-ops-for-pc-worth-buying-for-multiplayer-use - I get the same on Chrome 12 incognito (logged out, no extensions), Opera 11 (logged out, no extensions) and even Notepad (File → Open, then paste the URL address there -- the duplication is in the HTML itself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can [reproduce this issue in *Notepad* of all things](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/sidebar-modules-duplicated#comment-5006), that means serious business. Fixed with extreme prejudice.

<sup>Just a duplicate value in the site's ad settings, btw.</sup>